# Client authentication for Angular, iOS or Android using LDAP (active directory, OpenLDAP)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, openldap, auth0

I need a way to use LDAP for authentication, the use case is to allow client to use their own LDAP server to authenticate, I have there is 3 architectures to implement this need, what is the pros and cons for each architecture (implementation, security, performance)? do you suggest any other architecture?

**1st**
[image]
**2nd**
[image]
**3rd**
[image]

Comment: Hi, I have simular question, did you find an answer and choose one of these architectures?